# How to create Click To Call Link WITHOUT html

Tags: html, wordpress, call, tel

I am building 360 Virtual Tour website page using software. I want to setup click-to-call using URL links, WITHOUT "tel:". Normally we would use -> a href="tel:6281234567890" HTML code. But the software requires a proper link to start with "http://" or "https://", so the software rejected "tel:" link.

Research online so far only came up with "how to build click to call link using HTML". I want to build click to call link WITHOUT HTML.

Seems like a common requirements, but nobody is talking enough about it. So, Possible?

Found another Wordpress URL Shortener plugin that asks for "http" based link too, and they do not accept "tel:" link. Any recommendations that can do this will be deeply appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Try :

```
javascript:window.open('tel:6281234567890')
```